# Can the KeyRelease event be shared between a listbox and treeview widgets and if so how can one determine which called it?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

```
listbox = tk.Listbox(container, listvariable, height)

listbox.bind("<KeyRelease>", dosomethingelse)


tree = ttk.Treeview(container, **options)

tree.bind("<KeyRelease>", dosomething)

tree.focus()
```

Problem is the event for `listbox` fires first and resets my page.  I want focus to remain in effect for the `Treeview`.

Tried `tree.selection_set` before focus but it didn't work.  I'm considering writing additional code (flag) in the `dosomethingelse` function to jump around code that resets page.

Suggestions would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. "resets my page" could mean many different things. Also, you mention `tree.selection_set` but you don't call that anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: You can get the widget that fired the event from `event.widget` in your handler function (assuming your handler is set up to accept the `event` parameter), but without seeing more of your code it's hard to tell how that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause to my problem was focus ...

Not sure why but in my searching and pulling my hair out I stumbled upon an older posting by grigoryvp (much thanks for this !)

Treeview widget behaves totally different from listbox and combo.

```
tree.selection_set(items[0]) # highlights row only but no focus
tree.focus_set() # not sure what this does but you need it
tree.focus(items[0]) # sets focus
```